# small world networks properties

Tags: graphs, graph-traversal

Small-world networks have two properties: clustering coefficient and average node-to-node distance

my questions are: 1- Can a disconnected graph ( which may include multiple connected graphs) hold a small network property? 2- If a graph holds a small "average node-to-node distance" (around 4) but has a low clustering Coefficient (around 0.005 ) would it be considered a small-world network?